# Why showing it is null parameter?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, petapoco

I have wrote this code to see details in details view with petapoco. but it is not showing any data and it also showing null parameter. I have added and details view page.. here my database name FCBook and table is RMReceive and primary key is RrId.. please help to run this code successfully...

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var db = new PetaPoco.Database("FCBook");
            var rmr = db.Single<RMReceive>("select * from RMReceive where RrId= @0",id);
            return View(rmr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an expression here, your query probably won't work with raw SQL, try

```
var rmr = db.Single<RMReceive>(x => x.RrId == id);
```